# beginner website, when i zoom out layout changes, and general css tips

Tags: html, css

making a website for the first time and I found that when I zoom out, my layout size get messed up. can anyone help explain to me why? and how to fix it Thanks!
This is what its like at 100% zoom: http://puu.sh/peI6R/c7f45747a0.png
When I zoom out: http://puu.sh/peI80/f5fb16d6d0.png
Also, how can I make my footer have a vertical list on the left side? I tried using float: left but it just scrambled the words.

After trying to make this website, I realized that my CSS properties knowledge is HORRIBLE. I've only done the HTML/CSS/JS on Codecademy and maybe that's not enough, so any tips would be appreciated!

```css
    body {
      margin: 5px 225px 225px;
      background-color: #FFA500;
      font-family: Comic Sans MS;
    }
    
    .banner {
      background-image: url(http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Orange-space.jpg);
      height: 250px;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center center;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .heading {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #3232FF;
      border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    }
    
    .Content {
      width: 900px;
      height: 700px;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .Profile {
      margin-left: 100px;
    }
    
    .mypic {
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    .footer {
      width: 900px;
      height: 120px;
      color: black;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #aaa;
    }
    
    .footer ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    .footer li {
      display: block;
    }
    
    nav {
      display: block;
      background: #aaa;
    }
    
    ul {
      text-align: center;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 5px 100px;
    }
    
    a {
      color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Simon's First Website!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Simon's Portfolio">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Simon Fu First Portfolio">
        <meta name="author" content="Simon Fu">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="First.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="Content">
            <div class="heading">
                <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/yogscast/images/c/c0/Simon_Banner_png.png/revision/20140308175434">
            </div>
            <div class="base">
                <h1 class="Profile">Profile</h1>
                <figure class="mypic">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png" height="250" width="250">
                    <figcaption>My beautiful face</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>

        <div class="footer">
            <div align="center"><strong>Contact Me</strong></div>
            
            <ul class="left">
                <li>Email: dontmessiiii@gmail.com</li>
                <li>Melee: JK</li>
                <li>League of Legends: jk</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two comments: a) remove your email address from the question (you'll get spammed very quickly) b) Do not use comic sans as your font (it's dated by about 20yrs) - after that, try to give us more specifics about what you want to accomplish; wanting a vertical list on the left side is a bit generic - read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question - good luck on your journey as a website creator and welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: This is so cute...

Comment: @Tobi that was exactly my first impression :)
I think he wants to achieve responsive design?

Answer (score 2):

### What's happening?

*Follow me*

This is your layout, basically.

```
body
    banner
    nav
    content
    footer
```

As you don't use `CSS` to style our sections yet, all of them have `width: auto`. In simple words, and **only to understand this problem**, in the case we can say our sections have the width of your browser's window.

You styled your `body` element with `margin: 5px 225px 225px`, so in other words, bacause of the [margin shorthand property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp):

- top margin is 5px
- right and left margins are 225px
- bottom margin is 225px

So now our elements' width is the result of `100%` *(in this case, browser window's width)* - `225px * 2` *(because of left and right body's margins)*.

Then, you set content and footer's width to `900px`

```
.content {
  width: 900px;
}

footer {
  width: 900px;
}
```

So, if you back to our layout we see that

```
body             
    banner       has width: auto => browser window's width - 225 * 2
    nav          has width: auto => browser window's width - 225 * 2
    content      has width: 900px
    footer       has width: 900px
```

The width of `content` and `footer` are static, while the width of `banner` and `nav` depends of your browser window's width.

### How to solve it

Defining the width of `banner` and `nav`as you did with `content` and `footer`. You can do a div, called for example `container` to set the width off all element, so if you want to change it in the future you only have to modify one line.

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Height of `.banner` and `nav` must be defined like `.Content` and `footer` (900px). `margin:0 auto` is added to make it always center;

```
.banner, nav { width: 900px; margin:0 auto; }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Edited: Added explanation.